# Изменение размеров изображения на visal C#, wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Подскажите, как изменить размер изображения (jpg) в wpf проекте c#? На формах всё делается просто

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"C:\test.jpg"), 800, 600);
bmp.Save(@"C:\img.jpg");
```

Только вот с wpf класс Bitmap не выйдет использовать, как я понял.

Comment: Ну так добавьте референс на Forms, если так уж надо.

Comment: Добавьте референс, как предложил @VladD. Учтите, что `Bitmap` лежит не в `System.Windows.Forms`, а в `System.Drawing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, можно преобразовать GDI-битмап в WIC-битмап с помощью `Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap`. Правда есть нюанс, что освобождение хэндла `GetHbitmap` на совести вызывающего кода.

```
[DllImport ("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject (IntPtr hObject);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"C:\test.jpg"), 800, 600);
IntPtr handle = bmp.GetHbitmap();
BitmapSource image = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(handle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
DeleteObject(handle);
bmp.Dispose();
```

Во-вторых, можно воспользоваться классом `TransformedBitmap` с преобразованием `ScaleTransform` для изменения размера WIC-битмапа.

```
var resized = new TransformedBitmap(bitmap, 
    new ScaleTransform(
        newWidth / bitmap.PixelWidth, 
        newHeight / bitmap.PixelHeight));
```

Правда есть нюанс, что ссылка на оригинальное изображение останется в памяти (это неразрушающее преобразование). Для освобождения можно создать новый битмап и скопировать в него данные с помощью сохранения и чтения в поток или копирования пикселей... В общем, в WIC функционала больше, но простые вещи делать сложно.